# why do_anonymous_page() call pte_unmap() just after set a new pte entry？(linux kerenl 2.6.11 memory management)

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel

I am a newbie in linux kernel .Today i have a question about some linux kerenl 2.6.11 memory management code(plz check my code comments for my question) in **do_anonymous_pages**() and the code slice is following:

```c
if (write_access) {
    pte_unmap(page_table);
    spin_unlock(&mm->page_table_lock);

    page = alloc_page(GFP_HIGHUSER | _ _GFP_ZERO);
    spin_lock(&mm->page_table_lock);
    page_table = pte_offset_map(pmd, addr);
    mm->rss++;
    entry = maybe_mkwrite(pte_mkdirty(mk_pte(page,
                    vma->vm_page_prot)), vma);
    lru_cache_add_active(page);
    SetPageReferenced(page);
    set_pte(page_table, entry); /* here just set new pte entry */
    pte_unmap(page_table);  /* why unmap just we set new maped PTE?? */
    spin_unlock(&mm->page_table_lock);
    return VM_FAULT_MINOR;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read how the page_table was populated in the first place you will see it was pte_offset_map-ed first. It should be no surprise that there is a matching pte_unmap.

The page_table thingy IS NOT the pte thingy which is set here.

Rather, on certain architectures the kernel has a very limited address space. For instance i386 is able to address 4GB of memory. This is typically split into 3GB for userspace and 1GB for kernel. But all kernel memory typically does not fit into 1GB. Thus the problem is combated by temporarily mapping and unmapping various pages where possible, as needed. page tables of userspace processes, as can be seen, are subject to this behaviour. These macros don't map/unmap anything on amd64, which has big enough address space for the kernel to permanently map all physical memory.